# Cannot print the logs using FreeRtos in esp32-wrover

Tags: c, embedded, esp32, freertos

I recently started learning FreeRTOS on ESP32-WROVER and encountered an issue with printing logs. Despite my attempts, I am unable to see any log output. I am using Visual Studio Code (VSCode) as my development environment, and I have checked the Terminal tab, Output tab, and Debug Console, but no logs are displayed.

Following is the code that I am trying to run.

```
static const char* TAG = "MyModule";

void app_main(void)
{
    // Set the log level (optional)
    esp_log_level_set(TAG, ESP_LOG_VERBOSE);

    // Enable logging
    esp_log_level_set(TAG, ESP_LOG_VERBOSE);

    ESP_LOGV(TAG, "Starting the Log Test Program...");

    int counter = 0;

    while(1) 
    {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Iteration: %d", ++counter);
    }
}
```

I've also tried to explicitly set the baudrate to 115200 in the code (which I've checked is the default baudrate for the ESP32 UART), but I still didn't see the logs.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This got me puzzled:

> I have checked the Terminal tab, Output tab, and Debug Console, but no logs are displayed.

You are running this code on a device, but are expecting the logs in your IDE on another machine?

ESP32-WROWER has a dedicated serial port, which if configured properly will output the logs. For this, depending on your device, you usually use either a serial port available via USB on your board (like in ESP32-WROWER-KIT), or TTL-USB adapter.

Then, depending of the OS you are using for development, you use whatever tool you like to dump the output of a particular serial port. I personally use Putty on Windows and [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) (`screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`) on Linux.

This part of official documentation should help you: [Establish Serial Connection with ESP32](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/establish-serial-connection.html).

Comment: thanks so much for responding. 
The FreeRtos writes the output to the dedicated UART, therefore I was expecting to see the logs on my windows machine. And indeed this is the case, as soon as I used putty and serially connected it to the controller, the logs were Visible.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it helped to resolve your issue.